# Write a recursive algorithm to remove elements from a linked list. Write a recursive algorithm to add elements into a linked list

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, linked-list

I'm having some difficulties with writing adding and removing function.
Here's some code for displaying the list, searching and removing the list.

I know how to implement it iteratively, but with recursion, I have some problems.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct AddressBook
{
    string name;
    string surname;
    long long phone;
    AddressBook* next;
};

void delPerson(AddressBook*& head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        cout << "There are no persons in my book\n";
    }
    else
    {
        string pName;
        cout << "Enter name of person: ";
        getline(cin, pName);
        AddressBook* temp = head;
        AddressBook* curr = NULL;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            if (temp->name == pName)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                curr = temp;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
        if (temp == NULL)
        {
            cout << "There are no person with this name\n";
        }
        else
        {
            if (temp == head)
            {
                head = head->next;
                delete temp;
            }
            else
            {
                curr->next = temp->next;
                delete temp;
            }
            cout << pName << " was deleted from the book\n";
        }
    }
}

void display(AddressBook* head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        cout << "My book is empty\n";
    }
    else
    {
        AddressBook* temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Name: " << temp->name << endl;
            cout << "Surname: " << temp->surname << endl;
            cout << "Phone: " << temp->phone << endl;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}

void search(AddressBook* head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        cout << "My book is empty\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cin.get();
        string pName;
        cout << "Enter name of person: ";
        getline(cin, pName);
        AddressBook* temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            if (temp->name == pName)
            {
                cout << temp->name << " is found\n\n";
                cout << "Name: " << temp->name << endl;
                cout << "Surname: " << temp->surname << endl;
                cout << "Phone: " << temp->phone << endl;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
        if (temp == NULL)
        {
            cout << pName << " isn't found in my book\n";
        }
    }
}

void delMemory(AddressBook* head)
{
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        AddressBook* temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}

void addPerson(AddressBook*& head)
{
    string pName;
    string sName;
    long long pPhone = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        cin.ignore();
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter the name(press '0' to end): ";
        getline(cin, pName);
        if (pName == "0")break;
        cout << "Enter surname: ";
        getline(cin, sName);
        cout << "Enter phone: ";
        cin >> pPhone;
        AddressBook* bleah = new AddressBook;
        bleah->name = pName;
        bleah->surname = sName;
        bleah->phone = pPhone;
        bleah->next = NULL;

        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = bleah;
        }
        else
        {
            AddressBook* temp = head;
            while (temp->next != NULL)
            {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            temp->next = bleah;
        }
    }
}


int main() 
{
    cout << "=============== My Address Book ===============\n\n";
    cout << "1. To add person\n";
    cout << "2. To display all\n";
    cout << "3. To delete person\n";
    cout << "4. To search person\n";
    cout << "5. Exit\n";

    AddressBook* head = NULL;
    int choice = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1: addPerson(head);
            break;
        case 2: display(head);
            break;
        case 3: cin.get();
            delPerson(head);
            break;
        case 4: search(head);
            break;
        case 5: return 0;
        default: return 0;
        }
        cout << "=============== My Address Book ===============\n\n";
        cout << "1. To add person\n";
        cout << "2. To display all\n";
        cout << "3. To delete person\n";
        cout << "4. To search person\n";
        cout << "5. Exit\n";
        cout << endl;
    }
    delMemory(head);

    return 0;
}
```

And this is recursive solution, but I have troubles implementing add and removing functions

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct AddressBook
{
    string name;
    string surname;
    long long phone;
    AddressBook* next;
};


AddressBook* delPerson(AddressBook*& head)
{

}

AddressBook* display(AddressBook* head)
{
    if (head!= NULL)
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Name: " << head->name << endl;
        cout << "Surname: " << head->surname << endl;
        cout << "Phone: " << head->phone << endl;
        return display(head->next);
    }
    return head;
}

AddressBook* search(AddressBook* head, string pName)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        cout << pName << " isn't found in my book\n";
        return head;
    }
    if (head->name == pName)
    {
        cout << head->name << " is found\n\n";
        cout << "Name: " << head->name << endl;
        cout << "Surname: " << head->surname << endl;
        cout << "Phone: " << head->phone << endl;
        return head;
    }
    else
    {
        return search(head->next, pName);
    }
}

void delMemory(AddressBook* head)
{
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        delMemory(head->next);
    }
    delete head;
}


AddressBook* allMem(AddressBook*& head)
{

}


int main()
{
    cout << "=============== My Address Book ===============\n\n";
    cout << "1. To add person\n";
    cout << "2. To display all\n";
    cout << "3. To delete person\n";
    cout << "4. To search person\n";
    cout << "5. Exit\n";

    AddressBook* head = NULL;
    string pName;
    int choice = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1: allMem(head);
            break;
        case 2: display(head);
            break;
        case 3: cin.get();
            delPerson(head);
            break;
        case 4: cin.get();
            cout << "Enter name of person: ";
            getline(cin, pName);
            search(head, pName);
            break;
        case 5: return 0;
        default: return 0;
        }
        cout << "=============== My Address Book ===============\n\n";
        cout << "1. To add person\n";
        cout << "2. To display all\n";
        cout << "3. To delete person\n";
        cout << "4. To search person\n";
        cout << "5. Exit\n";
        cout << endl;
    }
    delMemory(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And those problems are?

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem, first you need to understand how  pointers work and then leverage them to iterate recursively.

Comment: What exactly are `delPerson` and `addPerson` supposed to do? You say you know how to implement them iteratively - show your iterative implementation, that would hopefully explain their purpose, at least.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, i think they are procedure to add a node and delete a node in the list

Comment: @AmitKumar To add node containing what information? To delete which node in the list? In what way does either of that require recursion, or iteration?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.
delPerson is supposed to delete a person from the linked list, and addPerson is supposed to allocate memory and allow to adding as many persons as you want.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: @Nick `delPerson` is supposed to delete *which* person from the linked list? How is `addPerson` expected to know how may persons you want to add - read your mind?

Comment: This is what I tried myself. I know how to implement this iteratively, but with recursion - no.

Comment: OK I see what you are trying to do. I think you can do the delete by asking for the user to delete then using the search function to recursively find them, then delete what search found. This means you need to remove the printing code from search, but search probably shouldn't print anyway. It should search. If the user wants the information printed, make another function for that. It's usually best to have a function do one simple thing.

Comment: So, how am I going to add a person?
Firstly I have to allocate memory, but how to do this using recursion?

Comment: Same basic thing. You always add to the end of the list, so you make a simple little function that recurses to the end of the list. Add person gets the person information from the user, calls the recursive end of list finder function, and inserts into the link returned by the end of list finder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's already posted misses a huge portion of the problem: Asking for user input in a recursive function just leads to pain. Either the user input is asked for in every iteration or additional control information needs to be passed to to tell the function to NOT ask for user input. Either is bad planning.

Instead insert another function or two. This is beneficial from a software engineering standpoint: A function should do the absolute minimum to do one job. Functions that do only one thing are very easy to comprehend, very easy to debug, and tend to be very short.

So we need a function to get an AddressBook from the user:

```
AddressBook*createAddressBook()
{
    AddressBook* bleah = new AddressBook; // terrible name, by the way
    // since we got the bleah first, we can directly assign to it. No need for
    // extra temporary variables.
    cout << "Enter the name: ";  
    getline(cin, bleah->name);
    cout << "Enter surname: ";
    getline(cin, bleah->surname);
    cout << "Enter phone: ";
    cin >> bleah->phone; // bad idea to store phone number as a number.
                         // For example a number can't record preceding zeros
    bleah->next = NULL;
    return bleah;
}
```

This is a simple stupid function that does nothing but make an AddressBook. To be honest, this should be an AddressBook constructor, but we can save that for a future question. Note also that there is none of the exit on 0 nonsense. This function makes an AddressBook. Period. If you don't want an AddressBook, *you don't call this function.* Let the menu handle exiting.

Next we need a function to find where the `AddressBoook` will be added. It looks like this is always the end of the list, so

```
AddressBook*& findEnd(AddressBook *& head)
{
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        return findend(head->next); // keep looking for the end
    }
    return head; // return the end.
}
```

Again, a simple, stupid function that does nothing but find the last next in the list. Note you get a reference to a pointer to an AddressBook. This allows you to happily return a next that points to NULL and replace the NULL with the new `AddressBook`

Which brings us back to `addPerson`

```
AddressBook* addPerson(AddressBook*& head)
{
    findEnd(head) = createAddressBook();

    return head;
}
```

Simple, stupid function that calls two other simple, stupid functions and adds a person to the list.

Apply a similar process to `delPerson`.

Note: I haven't run any of this. Could be a typo or two in there.

Comment: This is extremely useful!
Very appreciate mate!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simple example of how you can use a add to a linked list using recursion. You can apply this technique to your example above.

```
struct node{
    int i;
    node* next;
};
void add(node* cur, int i){
       if(cur->next == nullptr){
               node* n = new node;
               n->i = i;
               cur->next = n;
       }
       else
               add(cur->next, i);
}
```

You simply check to see if the next node is null. If it is, you've reached the end of your list and you can add your new node there. If not, call the function recursively, providing the current next node.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
typedef struct Nodetype {
   int key;
   struct Node * next;
} Node;

Node * newNode(int data){
    Node *temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->key = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}
Node* add(Node * head, int val){
    if(!head)
       return newNode(val);
    head->next = add(head->next, val);
    return head;
}

Node * delete(Node *head, int val){
     if(!head)
        return NULL;
     Node * temp;
     if(head->key == val){
         temp = head;
         head = head->next;
         free(temp);
     }
     else{
         head->next = delete(head->next, val);
     }
     return head;
}
```

You can change your code as per your need. I have assumed everything as integer.

Comment: very appreciate!

Comment: @Nick if that helps you, kindly mark it as an answer so that it helps others.